# How to get specific array within an array

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble getting a specific set of values from an array of arrays because the values come up as aundefineda. my array is stored in state and set up like this:

```
survey: [{names: ["sara", "tom"]}, {age: ["17", "33"]}, {col: ["blue", "green"]}]
```

To access just the names, I've been trying to use the line:

```
console.log(this.state.survey.names)
```

When I check, the console has "undefined" for the names. When I check the value of survey, it shows up as an array of arrays, where each nested array has two values stored inside.

I want to check this because I am trying to map out the nested arrays and mapping out Survey names isn't working because the length shows 0. I am successful in mapping out nested arrays when they are not stored in state, so I am wondering what I am missing or if my syntax is incorrect.

Comment: As per your array structure `[{names: ["sara", "tom"]}, {age: ["17", "33"]}, {col: ["blue", "green"]}]`, your array contain 3 object in 0, 1 and 2 index. `names` is available under 0 index. So you have to try `this.state.survey[0].names` to fetch all name.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access an array as if it was an object, instead of an array of objects.  A simple fix is - 
`this.state.survey.find(item => item.names).names`

In the long term, unless you have a reason to store this as an array, it would be a lot easier to reorganize and store as objects.  If you restructure this to be something like

```
survey: {
  names: ['name1', 'name2'],
  age: ...etc
```

If you are trying to say that `Sara` is `17` and her col is `blue`, why not just store that as a single object?